# What is the difference between static_transform_publisher and tf_echo command?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started learning tf that is one of the most useful package of ROS. I came across two command-line tool 1)`tf_echo` and 2) `static_transform_publisher`.

1. `rosrun tf tf_echo <source-frame> <target-frame>`
2. `rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher <X Y Z qX qY qZ qW> <source-frame> <target-frame>`

`tf_echo` gives a transformation between source and target link. While `static_transform_publisher` also gives a transform between two links.

Then why we have two command-line tool for same thing. If I mistaken understanding of these comand-line tool, please correct me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345249/what-is-the-difference-between-static_transform_publisher-and-tf_echo-command?/) by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2020-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If I mistaken understanding of these comand-line tool

I believe so.

`tf_echo` merely *prints* the value of the transform `<source-frame> -> <target-frame>`. From its [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#tf_echo):

> Print information about a particular transformation between a `source_frame` and a `target_frame`.

So this doesn't alter the TF tree, just prints information retrieved from it.

`static_transform_publisher` actually *publishes* (ie: broadcasts) a TF transform. Again, the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros#static_transform_publisher):

> Publish a static coordinate transform to tf2

This adds new transforms to the TF tree.

---

Edit:

> So `tf_echo` is like subset of `static_transform_publisher`? (output wise).

No, I would not say this is correct.

`tf_echo` is for humans. It displays information about the TF tree.

`static_transform_publisher` is for broadcasting a new TF frame and adds it to the TF tree.

Those are two fundamentally different operations.

> in addition to transformation between two frames, `static_transform_publisher` also creates a new node. ok got it.

If with "new node" you mean "it creates a ROS node (temporarily)", then yes, that would be correct, but only to be able to create a `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster`.

> Can you please explain what is usage/application of adding new transforms to the TF tree?

This would seem to come down to a basic understanding of what TF is and how it's used. Perhaps reading the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) would help here. Adding new information to the TF tree is an essential operation for any TF producer and consumer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-02-27**:
So `tf_echo` is like subset of `static_transform_publisher`? (output wise). in addition to transformation between two frames, `static_transform_publisher` also creates a new node. ok got it.

Can you please explain what is usage/application of adding new transforms to the TF tree?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-27**:
Perhaps you should read the TF documentation. It will explain.

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2020-02-27**:
There can be many TF broadcasters in your system, broadcasting different parts/frames of your robot. Going through the [TF documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) or watching [some movies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ra-nXIfPWdg) about it is really the first step.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-02-28**:
thanks, @gvdhoorn for the explanation. I read the full tf2 wiki page. Now, I have a better understanding of tf2 package. and thanks @Wilco Bonestroo for tf2 videos link.